# Cannot Run the below program of try and catch

Tags: java

```
public class exdemo1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 10, b = 0, ans;
        int arr[] = {10, 20, 30};
        try {
            ans = a / b;
            System.out.println("Division" + ans);
            System.out.println("4th Element" + arr[3]);
        } catch (ArithmeticException ae) ;
            {
                System.out.println(ae);
            }
         catch (ArrayindexoutofboundsException ae) {
            System.out.println(ae);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Format your code properly (copy/paste it as is and select the `{}` option). 2. What do you mean by *"Cannot Run the below program"*? It doesn't compile? It throws an exception? It does not do what you expect? Please be specific.

Comment: The current formatting makes this utterly unreadable. *Please* [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/184494) on how to properly format code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that your code is properly formatted, you will probably notice an extra `;` after the first catch block.

Comment: ans is declared after a and b.

Comment: @XavierDelamotte Yes just noticed. Thanks.

Comment: It gives the error where i have written catch (ArithmeticException ae)--it gives some hints here it is underlined in red and in the place where i have written catch (ArrayindexoutofboundsException ae)----- Here the error says there is not try. It also gives the error after compiling using the javanetbeans compiler     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ArrayindexoutofboundsException
  location: class exdemo1
 at exdemo1.main(exdemo1.java:17)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I got what the error is and where i was wrong thanks assylias

Comment: @user1560596 If you read all the answers that have been given, you should be able to make your code compilable.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what you mean exactly by that, but these are the issues I am noticing:

- Your array **does not** have a 4th element, it has 3 elements, the last of which can be accessed through `arr[2]`
- You can't divide by 0.
- `catch (ArithmeticException ae) ;` You must remove the `;` at the end of the line, you do not need that there.
- `ArrayindexoutofboundsException` The proper class is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I am assuming you know about the first two due to the catch statements.

Fixing those should make your program compile.

Answer (score 1):

It is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and not ArrayindexoutofboundsException

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semicolon after your first `catch`. Remove that. Also, I do not think `ArrayindexoutofboundsException` is a valid exception, should be `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed two programs together but only one Exception will be thrown.  You program does basically the same thing as

```
public static void main(String... args) {
     int a = 10, b = 0;
     int ans = a / b;
}
```

This will print the exception thrown.